# How to launch .ahk file when PC starts

Tags: autohotkey

```
^B::
Send, Hello World
return
```

This is my script-file made for AutoHotKey. How can I launch this file automatically when my PC starts? Now it is is all fine, but after reboot I've to launch it manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You’re gonna have to add it to your startup programs

Press Windows key + R, paste this file path in there and press enter: %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Right click -> New -> Shortcut

In the shortcut window click on “Browse” and then select your AHK file

Answer (score 2):

### to do that:

##### 1. press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

##### 2. type `shell:startup`

##### 3. copy paste your ahk file from the folder to the place which just opened

###### … and you‘re done!

Comment: In case you want to make another ahk script which does exactly what my answer says:

Comment: 1.Create a new ahk file ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍  ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍  ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍  ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍  ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍  ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍  ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍  ‍ ‍ ‍  ‍2.Paste `FileCreateShortcut, C:\Users\(username)\Desktop\(filename).ahk, C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` into the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the Windows Registry.

It Will Launch the .ahk File automatic after rebooting your System.

Try this AHK Code:

c:\examples\example1.ahk

```
^B:: 
Send, Hello World
return

^r::
RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run,example1,"c:\examples\example1.ahk" /background
return
```

You can press (Ctrl + r) it will put the values into the Registry.

Now you are ready to go. Everytime if you Start your PC, it will Automatic run the example1.ahk File.

Comment: Creating a startup item (below) seems like a better way to go.I'm surprised AHK doesn't provide a way to do this in its tray menu.